# Periodically outputting SQL table to a file

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to write a python script that continuously updates a file with the contents of a table in my database.

The table in the database is changing continuously, so I need to periodically update this file as well. I could do a select * query and get all the entries, but what would be great is if I could get the output table when applying the formatting of .mode column and .headers on.

What I've tried to do is create a SQL cursor and execute ".output file.txt", but that gives me an sqlite syntax error. I tried to call from the script os.sys("sqlite3 dbname.db 'select * from table;' > file.txt") but that doesn't seem to work either ("'module' object is not callable").

Is there a way for me to get the nicely formatted sqlite table?

Comment: Use `subprocess.check_call` and pipe stdout.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Just a follow up though: it used my sqliterc which had .mode column and .headers on -- is there a way to do this even if my sqliterc was blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import subprocess 
f=open('file.txt','w')
subprocess.call(['sqlite3', 'dbname.db', '-csv', 'select * from table'], stdout=f)
```

Comment: wow... while I was trying to post a fully verified and complete answer, someone posted a one-liner comment of the same idea.... talk about 1/2 a...

Comment: I've accepted your answer anyway! I was wondering if you could help with my follow-up though; my sqliterc is being used here which had .mode column and .headers on -- is there a way to do this even if my sqliterc was blank?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the -column and -header options to the sqlite3 command line tool to do the same thing. Alternatively, you put the dot commands and sql queries in a text file and pass a handle to this file as the optional stdin argument to subprocess.call (this redirects the standard input)